# Is "instant" hypnotism possible?

Tags: hypnotism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does an Erikson handshake induction induce a cataleptic trance?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10272/does-an-erikson-handshake-induction-induce-a-cataleptic-trance)

Is "instant" hypnotism possible? Derren Brown apparently hypnotises with just a single touch to the neck and eyes. The subject then appears to be able to walk in a trance state - and can be directed.

Comment: I'm wondering if any kind of hypnotism is really possible.

Comment: We've [already established](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/4813/23) Derren Brown is a magician who admits to being dishonest when on stage. Hence, this is not a notable claim; even he doesn't claim that what he appears to do on stage is true. Do you have any other places the claim is made?

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10272/does-an-erikson-handshake-induction-induce-a-cataleptic-trance

Comment: @Kibbee: We've had a number of questions circling around that. The answer seems to be "Yes, there is some sort of phenomena, but not as it is represented in stage hypnosis and in the movies."

Comment: Derren also never states he instantly hypnotises anyone - he makes quite a big deal of working with audiences to relax them and then choose suggestible members.

Comment: I don't see how this question covers ground that wasn't covered by previous hypnosis questions. I'm therefore voting to close. If you want to ask a new question, clearly define your terms. If you ask, "Does X put people into a trance" then you better provide a definition of what you mean by 'trance'.